# How to solve import org.apache.http.util cannot be resolved?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, build, build-target

I changed the project build target in MainActivity- CordovaLib from android 5.1.1 to android 7.1.1. After changing the build target it shows an error in the src/CordovaResourceApi.java that the import org.apache.http.util cannot be resolved. 
However when i change the build target back to 5.1.1 it does not show any error.
How do i solve this? Here is the build.gradle file in res/

```
 buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
// installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
// http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
// and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.2") {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+'
    }
} else if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.1") {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0+'
    }
} else {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.0+'
    }
}
  }

    apply plugin: 'android-library'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
     buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion
     publishNonDefault true

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
}
   }
```

Comment: did ur gradle has repo ?

Comment: paste your build.gradle

Comment: try using new gradle for http in app's gradle file

compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.2'



May be it will help

Comment: @W4R10CK what do you mean repo?

Comment: @MUlyaG I mean dependencies

Comment: @W4R10CK yes... i have pasted the build gradle codes above.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following in your gradle under `android`  :

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this value in build.gradle inside app folder

for example :-

```
ExampleProject/app/build.gradle <<== in this one 


ExampleProject/build.gradle <<== not in this
```

and it should look like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' // <<== add this

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```